# Writer Monad Example - from `do` Notation to `>>=` Notation

Tags: haskell, monads

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#reader) presents this Writer Monad example:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer  

gcd' :: Int -> Int -> Writer (DiffList String) Int  
gcd' a b  
    | b == 0 = do  
        tell (toDiffList ["Finished with " ++ show a])  
        return a  
    | otherwise = do  
        result <- gcd' b (a `mod` b)  
        tell (toDiffList [show a ++ " mod " ++ show b ++ " = " ++ show (a `mod` b)])  
        return result
```

How would this example be written with `>>=` rather than `do` notation?

Answer (score 2):

The following would do the trick:

```
gcd'' :: Int -> Int -> Writer (DiffList String) Int
gcd'' a b
    | b == 0 = tell (toDiffList ["Finished with " ++ show a]) >> return a
    | otherwise = gcd'' b (a `mod` b) >>= (\result -> tell (toDiffList [show a ++ " mod " ++ show b ++ " = " ++ show (a `mod` b)]) >> return result)
```

Comment: You could remove the `do` as well, it's still valid code without those two characters.

Comment: Indeed. I had removed the first do but forgot the second one.